# How i can connect two computer via two raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, bridge

```
Computer 1     <---- Ethernet ----> Raspberry pi 1  
Computer 2     <---- Ethernet ----> Raspberry pi 2

Raspberry pi 1 <---- Wifi ----> Raspberry pi 2 # AP/Client or any method
```

In ubuntu, I want to connect

```
Computer 1       <----------   ---------> Computer 2
```

Can I use bridget for this?
or How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not well defined. If you want to create a network where the rPI's can communicate with the PC's for various reason such as remote access control, File sharing, print sharing. If this is what you might want to do then go out and get a network switch, you can find them used at a second hand store.